# I'm trying to make a calculator with two input fields in CodeSkulptor using the module simplegui. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator with two input fields in CodeSkulptor using the module simplegui. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
This is my link: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user47_kHjBVKqs2k_1.py
I made two variables and I can't figure out how to change the variable to whatever the person inputs.

```
import simplegui

# intialize globals
Number1 = 0
Number2 = 0
result = 0


def output():
    """prints contents of store and operand"""
    global Number1, Number2, result
    print "Number 1 = ", Number1
    print "Number 2 = ", Number2
    print "Result = ", result
    print ""

def add():
    """ add operand to store"""
    global Number1, Number2, result
    result = Number2 + Number1
    output()

def sub():
    """ subtract operand from store"""
    global Number1, Number2, result
    result = Number1 - Number2
    output()

def mult():
    """ multiply store by operand"""
    global Number1, Number2, result
    result = Number1 * Number2
    output()

def div():
    """ divide store by operand"""
    global Number1, Number2, result
    result = Number1 / Number2
    output()

def enter1(t):
    global Number1
    Number1 = int(t)
    output()

def enter2(w):
    global Number2
    Number2 = int(w)
    output()

# create frame
f = simplegui.create_frame("Calculator",300,300)

# register event handlers and create control elements
f.add_button("Print", output, 100)
f.add_button("Add", add, 100)
f.add_button("Sub", sub, 100)
f.add_button("Mult", mult, 100)
f.add_button("Div", div, 100)
f.add_input("Number 1", enter1, 100)
f.add_input("Number 2", enter2, 100)


# get frame rolling
f.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works but you have to press enter on the keyboard after you have typed a number in either Number 1 or Number 2 input area's.
Unfortunately the output is not always the right one if you change a number because the action you last did is not remembered!
So you need to do a bit more coding for that...